# C# can't cast bool to int

Tags: c#, .net

We all know that in C# we can't cast bool to int. I wanted to see what is the binary representation of true with bitmask, but I can't use (bool & int).. I think the problem is the architecture desicion "true is true, not any number != 0" (C++) and I was wondering what the benefits of such an architecture are? What is so bad with the C true/false concept?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's clearer to the programmer when an integer can't be used for `true` or `false`.

`if (5 > 0)` is easier to understand rather than `if(5)`

It's the same reason why they don't allow fall through conditions in switch statements.  It's too easy to make a mistake.

Comment: I actually dislike the way they do fall through with switch statements in C# a LOT.  There are a lot of cases where fall through is very useful to have.

Comment: @Joseph: The case that's the least error-prone is still allowed - you can fall through provided you don't do any work first.  But having a case fall through after doing other "work" is not easily maintainable.

Comment: @Joseph: that it is useful does not mean that it's not error prone, or not easy to make mistakes with.

Comment: @Fredrik & Reed I understand, I just don't think it's very error prone, but I guess that's just my (uncommon) opinion.  I've never had a difficulty understanding the switch statement construct in the C++ sense, but I guess I can see why others might find it conceptually easier the C# way.

Comment: @Joseph I don't think it's understanding how it works is the problem they were preventing.  I think they are just trying to stop people from making typos, mainly forgetting to put the break statement at the end of a case.  I do agree with you there are scenarios where it would be helpful and at times a little frustrating that I can't use it,but I bet not being able to do has saved me more times than not.

Comment: @Kevin  If the desire is merely to prevent typos, then why not allow fall through, but raise a waring.  Like Joseph, I find fall-throughs useful.

Comment: @Nick, they could have made it where it raised an exception, but the language designers were pretty clear on this point.  They feel that the fall through in a case statement has value in certain situations, but it isn't worth the potential pitfall of accidently using it.  The real problem with a warning statement is that it often gets ignored.  With it being an error there is no possibility, and it takes me 30 seconds to refactor to not use fall through, but it takes potentially hours for me to debug an error, because someone made a mistake and forgot to add the break statement.

Comment: @Nick I thought of one other reason why you wouldn't want to have it as a warning.  Then turning on warnings as errors would prevent you from being able to compile the code, even though not having it be a compiler error would technically make it legal.

Comment: Given that "5" is not a literal but an int variable or the like (which mostly will be the case in the wild): `if (val > 0)` is **not** the equivalent of `if(val)` in C/++. The correct equivalent would be `if (val != 0)`. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37871324/2328447) Which imo should raise the question if the C# bool handling really is so much more error prone and understandable.

Comment: > It's clearer to the programmer //  It shouldn't be implicit cast.  explicit is good enough, as in case pf the byte. Also, it will greatly simplify some cases, such as inequality comparer implementations: return (int)rBool - (int)lBool; // also it will allow a micro optimization of not having condition (conditions may reset processor's instruction conveyor)

Answer (score 25):

In C integers are frequently doubly used as a normal number and a boolean, such as for loops that run while a certain number is not zero. That's a use which clearly has its merits for concise code, like a naïve strlen routine:

```
const char *s;
for (s = str; *s; ++s)
    ;
return (s - str);
```

but while short it masks the true purpose of that snippet, which essentially says "loop while the character I am looking at is not the null character". But written down it just says "treat it as a boolean when I feel like it, and as a number in some other cases".

This kind of double nature allegedly frequently leads to problems and it makes the code less readable (since you have to judge from the context whether a given usage of an `int` is intended as `int` or `bool`).

If you absolutely need to use a boolean as an integer you can either use

```
Convert.ToInt32(someBool)
```

as [Noldorin mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946688/c-cant-cast-bool-to-int/946718#946718) or roll your own with

```
someBool ? 1 : 0
```

Both of which clearly say that you are using an `int` (and not a `bool`).

Comment: The ternary operator is slow. Bool is a numeric type and should be castable for use in arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 20):

Just for information, `Convert.ToInt32(fooBool)` should tell you that `true` is represented by 1, and `false` by 0. (This is an arbitrary representation in the BCL, and not necessarily the one used it memory, however.)

The point here is, the bit representation really ought to be meaningless to any programmer. Booleans are meant to be used for specific purposes (i.e. flags), and shouldn't be mixed with ints, else the uses of variables can potentially become quite confusing.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the issue is some much about true/false or 1/0 as it is about the decision to make C# a strongly-typed language rather than a weakly-typed language.  There are many benefits (and some drawbacks) to a language being strongly typed.  One of the benefits is that it reduces bugs due to misuse (or incorrect use) of expressions.

For example,

```
int i = 0;
if (i = 1) {
   ...
}
```

won't even compile in C#, but it will both compile and execute incorrectly in C.

Choosing to make C# a strongly-typed language infers these benefits to C# programmers.  Even so, they could have introduced a conversion from bool to int (and back) if they choose.  I suspect that they didn't do so due to the potential for bugs like that above to be introduced.

Comment: this has nothing to do to "strong-typeness".
the if (i=1) it's possible in C because the assignment operator return a value (useful if you want to do a = b = c = 5)

for example, Python is strongly typed AND the assignment it's a statement, and doesn't "return" nothing. So doing something like "if a = 3:" it's an error.
But python itself has a rule saying "anything has a boolean interpretation": empty collectios, 0, the empty string are False, anything else True, so you can do
mylist = []
if mylist:
  something

Comment: Yes, but the reason that it allows the result of the assignment to be used in this context is because it is weakly-typed.  Almost certainly the intent is i == 1, which is a boolean result and in C# would be allowed in that context.  If C were strongly-typed the result of the assignment would be disallowed in this context, as it is in C#.  As it is, the result of the assignment is (erroneously, in this case) casually evaluated as boolean and thus a bug is born.

Answer (score 5):

we can use Convert.ToInt32, its definition is here:

```
public static int ToInt32(bool value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Nobody likes all of any other entity's decisions... just write your own converter (quick-&-dirty-like)

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = (bool)your_int ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

int n = (bBool) ? 1 : 0

Comment: I ALMOST have to down vote you for the use of Hungarian notation, yuk!

Answer (score -2):

You make a good point on these. However it does remove one shortcut.

With c, toggles can be easily done by the code "bBool = 1 - bBool".

If bBool is true (1), then 1 - 1 = 0. bBool changes to false.

If bBool is false (0), then 1 - 0 = 1. bBool changes to true.

Instead in C# I'm required to do a conditional to check the state, and then set it to it's opposite, which causes more work for the machine and me.

Comment: Am I missing something?  `bBool = !bBool;` does what you describe, no?

Answer (score -3):

number != 0, is too prone to error.

C# made a lot of design decisions to subvert common mistakes like this can lead to.

Comment: Not sure what your point is. Maybe you could elaborate a bit more.

Comment: By not allowing things like <code>if (27)</code> the language forces people towards a syntax that is more reliable like: <code>if (27 > 0)</code>

Comment: Ah, I see now that "number 1= 0" is a direct snippet from the original post. Perhaps putting a bit more context in your answer will help readers understand your point. In it's current form it doesn't make sense by itself. In general it is best to have some form of the original question within your answer, it doesn't need to be a direct quote but instead a rephrasing of the original question.