# Type casting boolean to int externally

Tags: casting, type-conversion

when internally the storage of boolean variable is in the form of an int variable,then why does it happen that when we try to type cast the boolean into int ,compilation error comes,

for example,

boolean a=true; // when this line executes the compiler then it internally converts the a vaiable to int type and it holds the value =1

so if i write

int rd=(int)a; // then why is this error??

that is when internally automatically boolean is converted as an int type variable then why externally we are not allowed to do type casting

Comment: Because there is no explicit or implicit cast between a `boolean` and an `int`. Such conversion can be error prone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# can't cast bool to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946688/c-sharp-cant-cast-bool-to-int)