# Does if (!(-1)) evaluate to true or false in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, negative-number, negation

I know that 0 and NULL evaluate to FALSE on their own and I know that a negative integer or a positive integer evaluate to TRUE on their own.

My understanding is that the NOT operation will happen after evaluating the expression, so `if (-1)` will evaluate to `TRUE`, then applying the `!` operand will mean `NOT TRUE` which equals `FALSE`. Is this the correct order of operations and is it correct that `if (!(-1))` will evaluate to `FALSE`?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: [Try it yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1471249b698860a)

Comment: Looking also for an answer related to the order of operations, not just the end result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The evaluation of `if (!(-1))` can be worked out by thinking about the operator precedences.

Firstly the unary `-` is applied to 1 which produces an integral `-1`. Then this value is logically negated by the `!`. This involves collapsing `-1` into a logical value. The rule for this in C is nice and simple for integral types: 0 is falsy and everything else is truthy.

Therefore `-1` is truthy and when the logical negation happens we get false.

Therefore this statement is portably false.

Answer (score 6):

In standard C, any non-zero (positive/negative) value is TRUE.

So, (-1) evaluated as TRUE and, !(-1) of-course evaluated as FALSE. Hence, if (!(-1)) will evaluate to FALSE.

Comment: Detail: "In standard C, any non-zero (positive/negative) value is TRUE." --> close.  Various objects have negative, positive, zero, NAN,null pointer, non-null pointer, complex, etc. values.  For `!` the only question is not what its value is, but if it  _compares equally_ to `0`.

Answer (score -4):

(-1) = 1111 1111 in binary and ! flips all bits so the byte would equal 0000 0000 which is equal to false.

Comment: You are confusing the `!` operator with the `~` operator - the **latter** flips all the bits.

Comment: You are correct and incorrect. They both mean the same. They both are complementary operators or NOT operators.

Comment: No! The `~` operator is a **bitwise** NOT but the `!` is a **logical** NOT. So, for a 4-bit `x = 0101`, then `~x` is `1010` but `!x` is `0000`.